# How to find the ever mapped network drive in Windows

Tags: windows-7

System: Windows 7 Enterprise

I have SQL Server service running on this desktop, and some databases' mdf files locate in a mapped network drive (D: drive). I re-start this server and then the mapped network drive disappear.

Is there any event log I can refer to so I can find out the original path this network drive mapped to?

This database server is set up by some other guy and currently refer to them is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

yes, very simple, (but i don't know the Mapped Drive logs but this will show you where you have attached the Database MDF file)

Just follow the Attached image below.

Open the Database Manager. -> Find the Attached Database and Right Click on it -> Select Properties -> in Properties Select Files section and there you can find the attached path

[image]

**Updated:**

and if you wanna observer the Mapped Driver Log. just Open the Registry Editor by Typing

`REGEDIT.exe` in your RUN and just open those trees until you find the **MountPoints2**
usually paths should be separated by \Server\Main Folder\Database but here it uses

### Server#Main Folder#Database so you have to identify by this way as well

[image]

Comment: thanks, although I can't select Porperties of that database now since the underlying mdf files are gone, Database Manager just raise exception when I do this

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to follow is using `net use` command in command prompt, but since it seems there's no connection to mapped drives, you could observe the registry:

[image: img_reg]

The registry key is `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2`

Comment: I didn't see something useful there, I can see two network drives (I am sure they are not used for database files usage), and a directory named "CPC" and it neither seems the D: drive I am looking for